# Gostaria de saber porque meu código não funciona, acredito que minha lógica esteja correta, mas está pegando lixo

Tags: c, array

Receberei 5 valores no vetor, tenho que fazer soma do maior deles com o menor deles,
está pegando lixo, o que tem de errado?
segue meu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int vetor[5];
    int i  = 0;
    int maior = 0, menor = 0, soma = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<5;i++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
        if(vetor[i+1]>vetor[i]){
            maior = vetor[i+1];
        }
        else if(vetor[i+1]<vetor[i]){
            menor = vetor[i+1];
        }
    }
    
    
    soma = maior + menor;
    printf("%d", soma);

}
```

Comment: Por que está comparando com `vetor[i+1]` se nem alocou algo lá ainda?

Comment: fora o que o @RafaelTavares comentou, quando estiver no último valor da variável i, que é 4, `vetor[i+1]` isso vai dar erro, vai estar tantando ler um valor fora do tamanho do seu vetor

Comment: To compreendendo seus comentário, @RicardoPontual Pontual. vou revisar meu código, obrigado

Comment: primeiro pode tentar uma coisa mais simples como `if(vetor[i]>maior) { maior = vetor[i]}` :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual saquei, realmente mais simples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim um dos maiores problemas do seu código era o lixo de memória que estava entrando no menor, pois como ele estava dentro de um ELSE IF, caso você só colocasse números maiores que o primeiro número, ele estaria sendo inutilizado. (ps: seu primeiro número sempre tem que ser o maior e o menor ao mesmo tempo)

*Para que você fuja desse problema, você utiliza o valor máximo de int para o menor e valor máximo de int negativo para o maior.*

Além de que para praticidade, na hora de compararmos qual o maior e menor valor, é ideal utilizar a variável de maior e menor que você declarou, pois você só comparava com vetor i+1, que sendo assim no final, você compararia com nada.

Segue o código corrigido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int vetor[5];
    int i  = 0;
    int maior = -2147483648, menor = 2147483647, soma = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i<5;i++){
        printf("Valor [%d] -> ",i);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
        
        if(vetor[i]>maior){
            maior = vetor[i];
            printf("maior says: novo maior %d\n",maior);
        }
        if(vetor[i]<menor){
            menor = vetor[i];
            printf("menor says: novo menor %d\n",menor);
        }
    }
    soma = maior + menor;
    printf("\n\nSoma do maior e do menor: %d\n", soma);

    printf("Vetor final: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d \t",vetor[i]);
    }
}
```